# PEAR: What version of xxx do I have?

Tags: command, pear, command-line-interface

I'm trying to figure out what version of HTMLpurifier I have installed through the pear CLI. I know there was a way to do so but I cannot find it.

I've tried

```
pear info htmlpurifier
```

But it just tells me that it doesn't exist. Yet when I make pear check for updates it will check the htmlpurifier's channel??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you just mistyped the name and you need to add the channel (at least the alias)

```
pear info hp/HTMLPurifier
```

Comment: pear info HTMLPurifier > No information found for `HTMLPurifier'
It was a good try, I think I remember having to refer to the channel somehow..?

Comment: @Mallow: Don't know, how long you wrote this comment, but its already added ;) Tried it myself and corrected it after that. Works for me now

Comment: haha YES!! This works! Is there a way to tell when a package has a prefix like hp/? I'm guess it's the same as the install name :P